# Get or set the values of controls of a form from a class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, class

How can I get the value of a textbox and store it outside the FORM.cs in a class method so that I can show that value on a label?
It is just for a test application. I want to have code that is independent from GUI.

Here is what I was trying:

Form.cs

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                       
     cueTextBox2.Text = value;
     Calling cal = new Calling();
     cal.setntags(value);
}
```

Calling.cs

```
public string setntags(string value)
{                
     value = tag1;
     MessageBox.Show("done");
     return tag1;    
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of `tag1` to `value`?

Comment: If you want keep `Calling.sc` out of GUI, then remove `MessageBox.Show()`, because this is GUI method. If you using messagebox only for testing then replace it with `Debug.Print("some message");` And check all message in output console

Comment: yes ,, it is for test only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer..what i found

```
           private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            int retVal;
            string local;
            Calling cal = new Calling();
            local = cueTextBox2.Text;
            retVal = cal.setNtagsDummy(ref local);
          if (retVal == 0)
            {
            label13.Text = cueTextBox2.Text;
             }
```

and in class file

```
    public int setNtagsDummy(ref string setndum)
    {
      int retVal;
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        setndum = "";
        retVal 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `setintags` you are assigning `value` the value of `tag`. Because you passing a copy of `button4_Click.value`, it will not change by the end of the function. If you want to change the value of `value`, you need to do this:

```
public string setntags(ref string value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done.");
    return value = tag1;
}
```

And call it like `cal.setntags(ref value)`);
The key here is the 'ref' keyword, that allows you to pass a variable by reference, which lets you change its value in a function.

Howeeer, if you want to store the value of `value` in `tag1`, you need to do this:

```
public string setntags(string value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    return tag1 = value;
}
```

Assignment assigns the left hand side of the assignment operator the value right hand side.